# IF ELSE THEN in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code in Excel's visual basic. I tried without a, b and c and just use Range("C2"), F2, G2, but it doesn't work too. I really don't know why this doesn't work, can someone help me ? :)

```
Sub pourcentremiseport()
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim c As Integer

a = Range("C2").Value

If a < 6 Then
 b = 9.6
 c = 0 

ElseIf a >= 6 And a < 20 Then
 b = 0
 c = 10

Else
 b = 0
 c = 25

 End If

 b = Range("F2").Value
 c = Range("G2").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: What is that you trying to accomplish here? Why do you have  b=Range("F2).value and c=Range("G2").value for?

Comment: i tried without a,b,c (only with Range("F2"), C2 and G2), but didn't work. I Have a table with some values and one cell use cells F2 and G2  in formula :/

Comment: It is better to use variables holding reference to specific cell than to call Range("X").value each time; it works faster and it makes coding easier. Now, it must be simple to solve ... I just don't know what do you need as result; can you upload screenshot and give an example of wanted result? The rest would be easy :)

Comment: yes, sure : 
http://i46.tinypic.com/25eyyr5.png

Comment: Hm it will be ok, if I enter in C2 10 and in F2 and G2 the result would be 0 and 10% (percent it's from format cells, i made it 
 already. And if i enter  22 in C2 the values in F2 and G2 would be 0 and 25% :)'I'm not sure if u understand me correctly :)

Comment: Okay we can solve the percentage cell: F2 formula =IF(C2<6;0;IF(AND(C2>=6;C2<20);0,1;0,25))

Comment: 10x a lot !!! I tried this code :  http://i45.tinypic.com/25jk0gp.png and it's work now.

Comment: Okay, please mark my question below (on the bottom) as good to go :)

Answer (score 0):

Are the last two lines supposed to be:

```
 Range("F2").Value = b
 Range("G2").Value = c
```

A general rule in VBA is the `=` sign sets the left object equal to the right one.

**Edit**

Without more information about 'why' the macro isn't working, it's hard to troubleshot.

Are you aware that you can use It/Then logic within excel formulas?

For cell F2 you can use: `=IF(C2<6, 9.6,IF(C2<20,0,0))`

And cell G2 could be: `=IF(C2<6, 0,IF(C2<20,10,25))`

Comment: I just tried your answer and it didn't work, so tried again without a,b,c and again didn't work :( It looks very easy but something went very wrong with this "program"

    If Range("C2") <= 5 Then
      Range("F2").Value = 9.6
      Range("F2").Value = 0
     
     
    ElseIf Range("C2") >= 6 And Range("C2") < 20 Then
     Range("F2").Value = 0
      Range("F2").Value = 10
     
    Else:
      Range("F2").Value = 0
      Range("F2").Value = 25
     
     
     End If

Comment: In the Ifs, also get the value using Range("C2").Value, and then compare... e.g. If Range("C2").Value <= 5 Then.... (Now what if the cell has a string or something else in, and not a number?)

Comment: It's digit. I don't enter any strings :]

Comment: http://i46.tinypic.com/25eyyr5.png this is the table :) i tried in excel formula, but it didn't work :/

Comment: Well the good news is that they are both not working for the same reason, so if one fixes they both should be fixed..

Comment: 10x a lot !!! I tried this code :  http://i45.tinypic.com/25jk0gp.png and it's work now.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with formulas:

Cell F2:

```
=IF(C2<6,9.6,IF(AND(C2>=6,C2<20),0,0))
```

Cell G2:

```
=IF(C2<6,0,IF(AND(C2>=6,C2<20),0.1,0.25))
```

It will be easier to handle error with Formulas than with VBA; less code to write :)

Comment: doesn't work, already tried :( :( :(  Here is screenshot of the table http://i46.tinypic.com/25eyyr5.png if it has any sense

Comment: I've updated my formula to fix percentage calculation. Kindly review and let us know if you have any questions or concerns...